# Why does practice direction 55A begin with 55.3?

Tags: england-and-wales, civil-procedure, rules-of-court

[Practice direction 55A](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part55/pd_part55a) seems to begin at 55.3. Why  are there no Practice Direction 55A rules 55.1 and 55.2, or where are they?

Comment: My understanding is that these slot into https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part55

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for [Practice Directions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practice_direction#:%7E:text=In%20English%20law%2C%20a%20practice,1998%20contains%20a%20large%20number) in this instance as the three previous [Part 55 Rules](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part55#cor) (i.e. Coronavirus – temporary provision, Interpretation, and Scope) do not require one.